# Bundles not created when using dotnet run in a project with a dotnet bundle task

Tags: asp.net-core

On an ASP.NET Core 1.1 I am trying to bundle and minify CSS and JS using BundlerMinifier so I added the following tasks on my .csproj (I am not using project.json anymore):

```
<Target Name="BeforePublish">   
  <Exec Command="bower install" />
  <Exec Command="dotnet bundle" />
</Target>
```

When I type `dotnet run` the project runs but the bundles are not created even if I have these tasks on the csproj.

Note: I typed `dotnet bundle`on the command line and the bundles are created so that is not the problem ...

This is the complete csproj file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.resx" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" Version="1.0.0-alpha-20161104-2-112">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Design" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final " />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />  
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.2-beta1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.2.306" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />        
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />

  <Target Name="BeforePublish">   
    <Exec Command="bower install" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet bundle" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

these are my **settings**:

**OS**               : Windows 10.

**IDE**              : Visual Studio Code.

**.NET Core version**: 1.1.

I'm afraid you don't have installed the ***BuildBundlerMinifier*** package. So, to be able to run bundling after running **dotnet build** command, you have to follow the steps bellow:

1. Run **dotnet add package BuildBundlerMinifier**, to install the missing package.
2. Run **dotnet restore**, to restore project packages.
3. Now, if you run **dotnet build**, you should see something like this:
   [bundling after building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOXaP.png).

You can see the whole proyect at https://github.com/pmargom/CarRentalMVC1.1.

Hope it helps!!